# GSM Power Supply

Tags: power, usb, gsm

http://www.powersystemsdesign.com/usb-modem-design

Can anyone tell me how the energy values in the table are calculated  in the link above,

Comment: Please improve your post by adding relevant details inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
BUT you will have to refine and extend the question.
 To me the gist of the article is clear enough.
 I have not gone through their figures in detail to look for errors but, if what they have written has no mistakes, then the article adequately explains what they are doing - so YOU need to better explain what you do and do not understand in order for us to help you with certainty.

---

But:

**Short:**

- Energy from boost converter Vin cap
  = Ein_boost
  = Eout / Zboost    where Zboost = efficiency of BC

Then

- EInboost = (Ecap_Vstart - ECap_Vfinish).
  Einboost = 0.5 x C x [VStart^2 - VFinish^2]
  Vstart = 5V
  Vfinish = 3.5.

  Rearrange and solve.

  C  = 2 x Einboost / [VStart^2 - VFinish^2]
  C = 2 x Eout / Efficiency_boost  / [VStart^2 - VFinish^2]

---

**Longer / Notes:**

The aim is to store energy at 5V to drive a 3v3 load and to convert the energy from 5V to 3V3 during a transmit pulse.
 THe argument is that because the higher voltage caps need less size to store the same energy then size can be reduced. I'd say that sounds a bit desperate in the context, but if that makes them happy ... .

Energy stored in a cap = 0.5 x C x V^2.
 If you increase V by a factor of (5/3.3) ~= 1/5:1 then capacitance required to store the same energy drops with 1/V^2 = 1/1.5^2 ~= 44% as large.

You also have to figure in buck converter energy losses. 
They say they get 93% efficiency so capacitance needs to be 44% as above x 1/0.93 = 0.44 x 1.075 = 47% of capacity at 3V3.

IF the buck converter could drain all the energy then you coiuld just cal;culate pulse energy, increase it by 1.075 and then use E=0.5 x C x V^2 to calculate cap size.
BUT a buck converter needs Vin >= Vout. They select Vin min = 3.5V - slightly above the 3.3V Vout requirued.

Cap energy discharging between Vstart and Vstaop = 0.5 x C x Vstart^2 - o.5 x C x Vstop^2
E  = 0.5 x C x (Vstart^2 - Vstop^2)
 Rearranging
C = 2 x E / (Vstart^2 - Vstop^2)
 Re add the 0.93 efficiency factor

C = 2 x E /0.93 / (Vstart^2 - Vstop^2)

That should match their results.
 If not then they have made a mistake :-) :-) :-)

Comment: i am sorry i did not explain it better.... I got the gist of the note.. but the question was to know how exactly the values were calculated...is says that vin = 5v Iin = 0.7A and Tx time  = 1.154mS . So the energy is calculated as E = 5 * .7 * 1.154m = 4.039mW . however in the note it says it is 3.433mW .So i wanted to know how he got 3.433mW . Thanks

Comment: @Lonewolf - you should put your expanded explanation into your question so others can easily see it. I went through their table and I do not get quite their figures. They may have changed some figure that the others were derived off and not updated the table OR I may have misunderstood what they are meaning. BUT overall it's quite simple.  Energy from boost converter Vin cap = Ein_boost = Eout / Zboost (Zboost = efficincy of BC). Then EInboost = (Ecap_Vstart - ECap_Vfinish). Vstart = %. Vfinosh = 3.5. Rearrange and solve.